# How to create Adhoc object containing simple types

Tags: c#, class

To pass values to some methods, you need to have object, that contains simple type fields.

i.e https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.languagegeneration.templates.evaluate?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable

Is there way to generate adhoc object and assign simple type (lets say string) to it, without defining a new class?

I have:

```
string myString;
```

I want to have below without creating the class for myAdhocObject

```
var myAdHocObject;
myAdHocObject.myString = myString;
```

This way I could pass it to the method from the link with minimal effort. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes.

- C# 7 supports Value-Tuples (`System.ValueTuple`).
- C# 3 supports Anonymous Types, though given these cause GC heap allocation I don't recommend using them. You also cannot use them in a method signature.
- You can also manually instantiate `System.Tuple<T...>`.
- If you want to forgoe type-safety you can use `dynamic`, *but this is not recommended*.

---

However, in the context of your question (w.r.t. `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.LanguageGeneration.EvaluationOptions`), because .NET uses nominative typing (rather than structural typing) you **cannot** pass Value-Tuples, Anonymous Types, or `System.Tuple` to methods that expect objects of a particular type - you must still instantiate an object of the correct type yourself.

Comment: Tuple actually worked, as "scope" parameter of `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.LanguageGeneration.Templates.Evaluate` is object type and it accepted `Tuple<string>`. Thanks a lot!